# How to reference to the existing object of class in Python from string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, instance

I've got the problem with reference to the object.

Function returns `string="nameofexistingclass"` and I would like to pass the string as an object and not as a class.

User choose in the GUI of the existing instance of `Person(self.name, self.ID)` --> string with name of choosen class --> set another object of different class demanding choosen class.: `Classify(person)`

Python demands to set the `self.name`, `self.ID`, but they exist before even choosing.

```
print(string.__class__)


class Person():
    def __init__(self, name, id):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id

class Classify():
    def __init__(self, person):
        self.person = person
    def classifyfunc(self):
        return self.person.id*3

Ann = Person("Ann", "2")
choosen_person = str(self.list1.curselection()) #"Ann"
classify1 = Classify(choosen_person)
classify1.classifyfunc()
```

Comment: You should store your Person objects in a dictionary.

Comment: Also parentheses when defining classes are only used for inheritance. So your empty parentheses `class Person():` and `class Classify():` are redundant.

Comment: @StamKaly Not *just* inheritance, although empty parentheses serve no real purpose.